# Robolectric - How does it work with URLConnection

Tags: android, mocking, robolectric

I am trying to test downloading and storing an image (any image) using Robolectric but I keep getting a 403. The URL is properly accessible and work with Android's VM, also works when I open in the browser.

Here is what I am trying to test.

```
try{
   URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("http://<any image url>").openConnection();
   InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
   // call a method to write to disk
} catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

My Roboelectric method fails when I try to get the inputStream. It always returns a 403. I looked at the FalseHTTP thing as well but it only seems to work with apache's connection.

Is this a Roboelectric problem or what am I doing incorrectly ? Robolectric is properly configured. RUnnables work. It fails over here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false) to allow the requests to actually go through instead of being intercepted.

Comment: My URLConnection, COnnection are not from apache. I have already tried that. Does not work for the code that I am testing. I would rather not change the code just so that I cannot unit test it.